# PHPUnit Test framework quit unexpectedly in PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm running PHPStorm 7.1 in Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10), and when I run PHPUnit tests, it says that the Test framework quit unexpectedly, and gives me "Process finished with exit code 0". However, it does look like the tests pass. If I make the test fail, It shows me the failures, and then says Process finished with exit code 1.

So I do know when tests are failing, but I don't get the red or green bar, nor do I get the list of tests on the left. I think my tests are passing, but I want to be sure.

In PHPStorm, I'm using MAMP Pro's PHP (5.5.18), and I've added that to my .bash_profile:

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

Has anyone experienced this? Any suggestions?

Comment: I've received that error message before when phpunit wasn't configured correctly.  Are you able to run the tests in the debugger to see exactly where they're dying?  You might have something catastrophic happening in one of the later-running tests.

Comment: **1)** PHPUnit version? You may need to update to PhpStorm v8 as v7 only supports PHPUnit 3.x. **2)** How PHPUnit is installed (PHAR file or composer package)? How do you init it in PhpStorm? **3)** Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186841/test-framework-quit-unexpectedly-when-test-passes-but-fails-gracefully

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne. It was the version of PHPUnit. I was using PhpStorm 7.x with PHPUnit 4.x. Fixed!